# Unreal Engine: Object Reference is not compatible with pawn Object Reference

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

Hello I am a beginner Unreal Engine developer learning with Blueprint and I am trying to take an imported FBX model and put a pawn control on it. Below is what I am trying to do. By the way, FbxScene_Test_Character is an actor.

[image: My code and error]

What can I do to get around this error? Do I need to add extra information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only `Possess` a `Pawn`, and `FbxScene_Test_Character` isn't one (it's probably a skeletal mesh actor).

Place a pawn subclass (such as `ACharacter`) in your scene, and in the properties for that character, assign the imported skeletal mesh. You can then use the placed character actor as an input for the `Possess` node.

[See "Setting up a Character" for more details](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/CharacterSetupOverview/index.html).

Comment: +1 for the explanation and link.  OP should also be aware that a character and a pawn are considered different by the Unreal Engine.